# Google return error 500 when i try to get accessToken

Tags: token, access-token, google-account, http-status-code-500

Since this morning, i try to get my accessToken from GoogleAPI but it doesn't work at all, and i don't know why.

I send my post request to this address : https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token (address from the json file generated by the account service, with the private_key, project_id etc)

And everytime i get this http answer : `{ "error": "internal_failure" }`

My Header jwt:

```json
{
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/homegraph",
    "nbf": 1542816703,
    "exp": 1542820303,
    "iat": 1542816703,
    "iss": "myaccount@google.com",
    "aud": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
}
```

And my call :

```cs
var jwtResult = ConstructJwt();
var paramaters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
paramaters.Add("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");
paramaters.Add("assertion", jwtResult);

var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri(_serviceAccount.TokenUri),
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(paramaters)
};

this._client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
this._client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

var response = await this._client.SendAsync(request);
var accessToken = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AccessTokenResponseModel>();
```

If someone has an idea ...
Thanks for answers.

Comment: seeing lots of errors in the APIs & services dashboard as well

Comment: @andryuha i have none errors in the homegraph API metrics... 
And this morning i had an http error 400, that's should be tracked but i have nothing on the board.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
I had to put"kid" parameter into the accesstoken header.

```
var header = new JwtHeader(signingCredentials);
header.Add("kid", _serviceAccount.PrivateKeyId);
```

And change the "token_uri" from the json file generated by the AccountService.
"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token" => "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"

Now it works.